# Using Flavors with Flutter on iOS: ${PRODUCT_NAME} not working as intended

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, android-productflavors

So I am trying to setup *flavors* in the iOS app of my Flutter project. My aim is to be able to have multiple *flavors* of the app simultaneously installed on my iPhone.

In order to achieve this, I stumbled upon this official guide: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors.

But I have encountered issues where the app ended up being named "Runner" and I could not even have multiple apps installed on my iPhone.

---

**Let's start at the beginning.**

I have **3 flavors** (schemes):

- `dev`,
- `mr`, and
- `prod`.

[image: screenshot of the schemes]

[image: Manage Schemes modale screenshot]

Each are defined for **Debug**, **Profile** and **Release** and I have removed the original ones.

**Next step, the guide shows how to define unique bundle identifier for each scheme which in my case are as follow:**

[image: Screenshot of all unique bundle identifiers]

Then we move on to the `Product Name` and I did exactly like the guide:
[image: Scheme's product name screenshot]

**Last step is to edit some fields in the `Info.plist`.**

This is where the guide is **very confusing**, because it says to set `${PRODUCT_NAME}` to `Bundle Display Name` however, in the following screenshot it clearly says `CF Bundle Display Name`. I tried to find the latter in Xcode but there is no such choice when browsing available keys ("+" button next to "Information Property List").

Then I opened `Info.plist` in Android studio to write the following keys:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>My Flutter App</string>
```

Back to Xcode, this is how it looks like now:
[image: Screenshot of Info.plist in Xcode]

Unless I am wrong, to my understanding:

- `CFBundleDisplayName` corresponds to `Bundle Display Name` from the written text in the guide,
- while `Bundle Display Name` from the guide's screenshot corresponds to `Bundle Name` in my `Info.plist` (or `CFBundleName` in the raw version).

---

Then I try to build the app with the `dev` flavor:
[image: Screenshot of build configurations in Android Studio]

But on my iPhone running iOS 12, the app is titled "Runner". Then, if I use the `main.dart (mr)` build config (which uses the `mr` flavor), the new build replaces the existing one, and it is still named "Runner".

So I believe that:

- the naming does not work
- the flavor system does not work as well.

Also what further confuses me, is why the guide asked to write Product Names such as "Debug Free" (or Debug Dev in my example) ??? Is that supposed to be the app name ?
I am not actually looking for different names at the moment, but I want to be able to have the three flavored apps installed on my iPhone.

What am I doing wrong?

---

*Note: the flavors system worked perfectly fine on Android*

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you solve it some how?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this too. The tutorial only said to change in Project level. However, when I check at Target level, the product name is set to "Runner". Hence, all the product name will be named as Runner.

So I changed the target product name to $(PRODUCT_NAME). Then, it will properly use the PRODUCT_NAME value from the Project level.

[image: Changet target.productName]